# How is SBT determining the scalajs-react version to download

Tags: scala, sbt, scalajs-react

I'm using SBT 0.13.7 to build a Scala 2.10.4 project. I'm using Artifactory basically as a local offline cache (although this problem is present when I try to populate it, online).

I've included the scalajs-react library with

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react" %%% "core" % "0.11.2"
```

but I get

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react#core_sjs0.6_2.10;0.11.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I have Artifactory pointing at

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/
```

among other repos, but it looks like this has 0.6_2.11

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/japgolly/scalajs-react/core_sjs0.6_2.11/

How has SBT determined that it needs 0.6_2.10, and can I influence it in some way?

EXTRA:

Looks like I can point it in the right direction with

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react" %%% "core" % "0.11.2" from "http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/japgolly/scalajs-react/core_sjs0.6_2.11/0.11.2/core_sjs0.6_2.11-0.11.2.jar"
```

but that seems to completely bypass Artifactory.

Comment: You cannot include a 2.11 dependency in a 2.10 project. You need to move to 2.11 first.

Comment: And suddenly the _2.11 makes sense. I can see that there's a core_sjs0.5_2.10 available at that maven repo -- is there a reason it's going for 0.6_2.11 rather than 0.5_2.10?

Comment: Ah -- moving to 2.11 and using libraryDependencies += "com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react" % "core_sjs0.6_2.11" % "0.11.2" ?

Comment: The `_sjs0.6_2.11` prefix is automatically added by sbt when you use `%%%` instead of `%`. It reads your configured Scala.js and Scala version.

Comment: Great, thanks --  I'd be happy to accept that as an answer ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use scala-js-react 0.5.4 with Scala.js 0.5.X. It's the last version to support 2.10 (see [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.japgolly.scalajs-react%22%20AND%20a%3A%22core_sjs0.5_2.10%22)).